# Headless RP 4 setup for Mac; getting "mkstemp: No such file or directory found"

Tags: headless, pi-4, raspbian-buster, macos

I'm brand new to Raspberry Pi. I bought a RP 4 kit from Amazon with the goal of creating a NAS Box to access external hard drive files over my Wifi. I have a MacBook Pro, running Mojave 10.14.6

Steps taken:

1. Connected 32 GB SD Card to Mac with card adapter
2. Formatted SD card to MS-DOS (FAT)
3. Downloaded Raspbian Buster Lite from Raspberrypi.org
4. Downloaded and installed balenaEtcher from balena.io
5. Installed Raspbian Buster Lite onto SD card with balenaEtcher
6. In Terminal, entered "touch /Volumes/boot/ssh" to create SSH onto SD card
7. In Terminal, entered "touch /Volumes/boot/wpa_supplicant.conf" to add networking information
8. In Terminal, entered "nano wpa_supplicant.conf" to edit file
9. Copy/pasted the below code, changing network name and password to my own network, doublechecking to make sure I entered information correctly

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="NETWORK-NAME"
    psk="NETWORK-PASSWORD"
}
```

10. Control+X to exit nano, saved changed, closed Terminal
11. Inserted SD card into Raspberry Pi 4
12. Opened Terminal, entered "ssh-keygen -R raspberrypi.local" to connect to RP 4 over my wifi
13. Received error "mkstemp: No such file or directory"

I repeated the above steps twice to make sure I did everything correctly, but I received the same error.

Any thoughts on how to get past this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are about 10 steps missing between 10 and 11

Comment: @Milliways I’m all ears. Any direction you can point me to would be appreciated.

Comment: I only do this once when a new OS is released (and use a keyboard for initial setup) but you need to go through the setup process to set locality, expand root etc. To do this headless you should connect to the Pi by IP. There is no need to run keygen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to generate a key to connect to your rpi.

Just connect (via ssh) to your pi with `ssh pi@<hostname or IP>`

I don't think it will resolve as `raspberrypi.local`, I have mine resolving as `raspberrypi` - but I'd first make sure it gets onto your network (via your router/whatever you use for your wifi or `arp -a` on mac) and use its IP address if the name does not resolve.

Default pi password for buster is `raspberry` - don't forget to change it on your first login.